# Flutter what is the Difference between using `pushReplacementNamed` and `pushReplacement` when pushing a new route?

Tags: flutter, dart

I know that `pushReplacementNamed` takes the name of the route and passes it with the route settings to the `onGenerateRoute` with that name and pushes on the `Navigator` the page returned by that function, and I know that `pushReplacement` takes the page route directly as an argument, but what I am asking about is when should I use one instead of the other, is there a specific use case of each one or is it just a matter of preference?

Comment: Actually when you are working on large scale apps, you should follow the name route convention for a better organization, passing the direct route is recommended for smaller apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a matter of preference, but I prefer the `pushReplacementNamed` one. The main difference is the one you have already mentioned - the `pushReplacementNamed` goes through the `onGenerateRoute` callback and then returns the next route. This way it is easier to separate the navigation logic and keep it in a separate file. All your routes could be defined under `onGenerateRoute` method, your UI code is not tightly coupled with specific pages - you can just simply pass the route name. And that's also the reason why `pushReplacementNamed` contains the `arguments` parameter - since the next route does not know where it was called from, you can pass the needed data using the parameter.

Comment: that's what I was thinking, though imo this introduces boilerplate code when writing if/else or switch statement to check the route name, thanks